# Django - Get sum of field where 2 other fields are equal

Tags: sql, django

I have a table with fields `bytes_in`, `mac_src`, and `mac_dst`.
I want to get the sum of field `bytes_in` of all rows where the field `mac_src` and `mac_dst` are equal, and then sort this sum from highest to lowest. The Queryset returned should have just one entry per `mac_src` and `mac_dst` value.

In other words, I need to sum up the field `bytes_in` as if `mac_src` and `mac_dst` were the same field with the same value.

Thanks.

```
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
| mac_src           | mac_dst           | bytes_in |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
| aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa | bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb |       10 |
| bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb | aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa |       20 |
| cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc | aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa |       30 |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select mac_src,sum(case when mac_src=mac_dst then bytes_in else null end)
from table
group by mac_src
order by sum(case when mac_src=mac_dst then bytes_in else null end) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried running it using the Django raw() method but it returned empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

items = (
    Item.objects
    .filter(mac_src=F('mac_dst'))
    .values('mac_src', 'mac_dst')
    .annotate(sum_bytes=Sum('bytes_in'))
    .order_by('-sum_bytes')
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Looking at other examples online, I agree with you that it should work. I manually checked to make sure that there are matching values for `mac_src` and `mac_dst`, and I can confirm there are.

Comment: Could you provide example of models and values where it doesn't work?

Comment: I should have been more specific with my question, I need to find the sum where `mac_src` and `mac_dst` and equal **and in different rows**. I've added an example of 3 rows. If I wanted to find the sum of `bytes_in` where `mac_src` == `mac_dst`, it would return 60 for where `mac_src` and `mac_dst` == `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa`, and return 30 for where `mac_src` and `mac_dst` == `bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  t1.mac_src as mac,
  t1.sum_bytes_in + t2.sum_bytes_in as sum_bytes_in
from
  (select
    mac_src,
    sum(bytes_in) as sum_bytes_in
  from tbl
  group by mac_src) as t1
  inner join
  (select
    mac_dst,
    sum(bytes_in) as sum_bytes_in
  from tbl
  group by mac_dst) as t2
  on t1.mac_src = t2.mac_dst
order by sum_bytes_in desc
```

This assumes that row.mac_src != row.mac_dst for any row.

Comment: Can you explain your solution?